# load and remove swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a problem in my app
i set many buttons in the main swf each button load different swf
the problem happens when i load a swf that contain sound 
even i remove it to load another one the sound still play in the background
i can't find a way to remove the swf with its sound

```
if(e.target.name=="gamepage")
    {
        removeChildAt(0)
        mycontent.addChild(myLoader);
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("game.swf"));
        nextpage.visible=false
        prevpage.visible=false;
        nextbtn.visible=false;
        prevbtn.visible=false;
        Tweener.addTween(mycontent, {rotation:360, time:5});
        i=0;
        }
```

i also used the unloadandstop but it didn't work

```
Loader(mycontent.getChildByName("myloader")).unloadAndStop();
        mycontent.removeChild(mycontent.getChildByName("myloader"));
```

Comment: `mycontent.removeChild(myLoader);` or `myLoader.parent.removeChild(myLoader);` ...

Answer (score 0):

It would be a comment but I am under the limit,

It wont stop if you are publishing sound in swf using "event" synchronization.